# AngularJs updating the URL for $http method dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I am trying to make an infinite scroll in Angular. The data items I want to show on my page are being served by a third party API and the URL looks like:

http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1

Now I am making a success ajax call using $http to the server and I have created a directive that on scroll will load the more Items from the url. But I can't get to update the URL, as soon as I start scrolling I would want my URL to become like:

http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=2
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=3
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=4
....

However everytime I scroll the URL just becomes:
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1
http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=1

which means the page parameter is never updated or even if it is the Shttp never executes it properly. Can some one tell me how to update the URL param in $http which pulls data from thirs party API.

The code looks roughly something like below:

```
var page = 1;
        var url = 'http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=' + page;
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data, status, config, headers) {
                $scope.page = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                    $scope.totalTags = data.items;
                    $scope.page += 1;

                }

            $scope.loading = false; 
        })
            .error...//rest of the stuff
```

Comment: In your code you are always setting `page` or `$scope.page` to `1`?

Comment: @Chandermani: I think I am updating it at 
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                    $scope.totalTags = data.items;
                    $scope.page += 1;

                }
but it wont update actualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with your code :

- var page and $scope.page are two different variables; you use the former to select the page in your $http request but never increment it. That's why you always get page 1.
- your loop doesn't do what you want it to do : you replace your data a hundred times instead of appending the new data to the existing set, and you increment $scope.page a hundred times instead of once (but you don't use $scope.page so it doesn't do anything, especially since you put it back to 1 everytime you retrieve data).

Try this code snippet instead :

```
$scope.page = 1;
var url = 'http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page=' + $scope.page;
$http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, config, headers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            $scope.totalTags.push(data.items[i]);
        }
        $scope.page += 1;
        $scope.loading = false; 
    })
    .error...//rest of the stuff
```

Comment: Thanks For your response, I was so engrossed with this that I completely messed the loop logic. but I think the problem still remains the same. The url wont update. What your code is doing is getting the items from the url http://example.com/item/data/?param=item&pagesize=100&page= and appending the same again and again. so I get same API responses appended again and again. e-g
[a,b,c] then [a,b,c,a,b,c] then [a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c] rather it should be [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]. Hope that is clear.

The bottom line is $scope.page isn't getting added and appended to URL, not sure how can that be acheived

Comment: can you show a bit more of the last version of your code ? This is probably something very minor, like the variable being misspelled are misplaced.

Comment: I put something in a bin, but I  issue isnt reproducible:
http://jsbin.com/manaxafiqoje/1/edit?js

Comment: Your first two lines are misplaced : you should define the base value of your variables outside of the function you are calling. Otherwise, they are reset each time. They should be defined somewhere in your controller outside of loadMoreItems

Comment: Makes sense, but that doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the same kind of logic that I wrote, only with mock data instead of the $http call. It works, so you might want to double-check where you declare and update your variables, because I am almost certain this is the root of your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6969/

Comment: Thanks a Ton for your help. It certainly works but I think $http doesn't work the same way. I think you can't fire any requests to $http like get/post/... the way we are trying to do. May be this could be a security breach, there should be a way around for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, otherwise I don't see how you could have retrieved the first page. Have you checked the syntax of the http URL ? Maybe it is pg= instead of page= ? This is about the only other reason I can see for the behaviour you are experiencing. Do you have any control over it ? Is it available online ?

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can put up a fiddle to demonstrate this with some live http data. Please keep watching this space. I appreciate this.

Comment: OKay, I have put up a fiddle for you with the issue reproduced , Look at the console which never updates the page and url always comes the same:
http://jsbin.com/gaxarekisozu/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have created a directive for infinite scroll, which means as you scroll it will load the more tags from API, but in my case it just loads the tags from &pagesize=70&page1 again and again, It should actually be &pagesize=70&page=1, &pagesize=70&page=2 , &pagesize=70&page=3 ....

Comment: You forgot to uncomment the $scope.page += 1 ; I just did and it mostly works. The directive seems to sometimes skip a page, might want to look into adding a small timeout maybe. But otherwise, it works

Comment: Thanks a Ton, I had some other problem that made me it to comment it, I now realise it is working to some extent but still a lot of work to do, I need to load the tags in small amounts and not in chunks of 70. A BIG THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate the url and parameters how the function allows you to, then it makes it much easier to make changes to your parameters.

```
 var url="http://example.com/item/data/";
 var params = {
    param:"item",
    pagesize:199,
    page:page
 };
 params.page = 2;

 $.get(url,params,function(data){});
```

Comment: Are you telling something like:
http://jsbin.com/budufitebadu/2/edit

I didnt get your answer?